# Annotate in a column when boolean value changes in a different column in sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to annotate the transaction type when a boolean value changes in a column in a table

```
ID   REVENUE   TERMINATED_PLAN  START_DATE        END_DATE
1      0           FALSE        2020-06-10       2021-06-09
1      5000        FALSE        2020-06-10       2021-06-09
1      7500        FALSE        2020-06-10       2021-06-09
1      15000       FALSE        2020-06-10       2021-06-09
1      10000       FALSE        2020-06-10       2021-06-09
1       0          TRUE         2020-06-10       2020-09-09   
1      5000        FALSE        2020-10-10       2021-10-09
```

This is the mock data what I have and I need to annotate whenever there is the change in the revenue. Let's say the revenue increased from 5000 to 7500 that means the customer upgraded the plan and the annotation should be "**expansion**" and if the they downgrade the annotation should be "**contraction**". When the revenue goes to 0 it means the customer churned we annotate it as "**churn**" and when that happens the Terminated plan becomes True and End_date updates to the day they churned. Sometimes the customer might come back and the revenue goes from 0 to some value(here 5000) and that should be "Re Activation" and when that happens the Terminated_plan becomes False and start_date and end_date fields are updated

I was able to do every thing except the reactivation part and I am bit confused on how to tackle that. One way to do it when the boolean value changes from True to False we can annotate it as **Reactivation** but not sure how to put that as a script.

This is the query I used to create a field called transaction

```
select 
id,
revenue, 
start_date,
end_date,,
TERMINATED_PLAN,
revenue - lag(revenue, 1, 0) over (partition by id order by updated_at asc) as diff_mrr,
case when revenue>0 and TERMINATED_PLAN = FALSE and month(start_date) = month(current_date) then 'New Business' 
     when TERMINATED_PLAN = TRUE and diff_mrr < 0 then 'Churn'
     when diff_mrr <0 then 'Contraction' 
     when diff_mrr >0 then 'Expansion'
     when revenue > 0 and month(start_date) = month(current_date()) then 'Reactivation' 
     end as transaction
from diff_mrr_t
group by 1,2,3,4,5
order by updated_at asc;
```

P.S: There's also another field called updated_at which populates whenever there is a change in revenue

```
ID   REVENUE   TERMINATED_PLAN  START_DATE     END_DATE   DIFF_REV   TRANSACTION
1      0           FALSE        2020-06-10    2021-06-09     0        New Business
1      5000        FALSE        2020-06-10    2021-06-09    5000       Expansion
1      7500        FALSE        2020-06-10    2021-06-09    2500       Expansion
1      15000       FALSE        2020-06-10    2021-06-09    7500       Expansion
1      10000       FALSE        2020-06-10    2021-06-09   -5000       Contraction
1       0          TRUE         2020-06-10    2020-09-09   -10000      Churn
1      5000        FALSE        2020-10-10    2021-10-09    5000       Reactivation(Expected but shows as New Business with the current logic)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am using snowflake database to solve this issue.

Comment: How come the first row showing `New Business` where the `revenue` value is `0`?

Comment: That is when the customer signed up

Comment: But how `revenue>0 and TERMINATED_PLAN = FALSE and month(start_date) = month(current_date) then 'New Business' ` this is passed ?

Comment: So this is the data of the customer who signed up in June that's why you can see new business

Comment: Okay, I know what you mean now. The first record should be always New Business bc we want to see new business only once in the whole customer life cycle and with that logic new business appears every month. That's a good catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood we also need to track the previous terminated_plan and then check it while setting for `Reactivation`,

Not completely sure but could you try with below,

```
select 
  id,
  revenue, 
  start_date,
  end_date,
  terminated_plan,
  lag(terminated_plan,1) over (partition by id order by updated_at asc) as prev_plan,
  revenue - lag(revenue, 1, 0) over (partition by id order by updated_at asc) as diff_mrr,
  case when    revenue > 0 
           and terminated_plan = FALSE 
           and month(start_date) = month(current_date()) 
       then 
          'New Business' 
       when    terminated_plan = TRUE 
           and diff_mrr < 0 
       then 
          'Churn'
       when diff_mrr < 0 
       then 
         'Contraction' 
       when diff_mrr > 0 
       then 
         'Expansion'
       when    revenue > 0
           AND prev_plan = TRUE
           AND terminated_plan = FALSE
           and month(start_date) = month(current_date()) 
       then 
         'Reactivation' 
       end as transaction
from diff_mrr_t
group by 1,2,3,4,5
order by updated_at asc;
```

Comment: This code doesn't execute and when the syntax mistakes are corrected it produces wrong results. But it looks like it was marked as the correct answer. Might want to update it with working code.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: Thanks for the hint. So is that the reason for down vote ? I believe sometimes while answering you might not have the right infrastructure in your hand but the logic you derive matters and most importantly OP is satisfied with that.

Comment: While your answer might be helpful, it is incomplete and gives incorrect results. It might meet OP's requirements but it doesn't help others who might stumble across the question and answer.  But I removed the downvote since OP did indeed accept it despite this - because you did make an effort to answer.

Comment: The fact that OP mentioned , he was able to derive all apart from `Reactivation` logic where I suggested to check the previous value for `terminated_value` which you have also done the same way( beside you removed the date check as compare to the code in original question) . When you say wrong please be specific which part you are referring ?

Comment: Using your query with the example data will result in the first record having a NULL Transaction and a "Expansion" for the last record. The last record would never reach the case statement for reactivation because it would fall into your Expansion logic "when diff_mrr > 0". The first record returns a NULL because you don't have a default in your LAG and you are not checking for NULL in your case statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. I made the assumption that the first record represents New Business despite revenue (revenue doesn't have to be >0).  Then I used the  TERMINATED_PLAN flag to check if the account is being reactivated versus expansion.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 0 AS REVENUE, FALSE AS TERMINATED_PLAN, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-08-10') AS START_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-08-09') AS END_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-08-10') AS UPDATED_AT
  UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS ID, 5000 AS REVENUE, FALSE AS TERMINATED_PLAN, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-08-10') AS START_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-08-09') AS END_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-08-10') AS UPDATED_AT
  UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS ID, 7500 AS REVENUE, FALSE AS TERMINATED_PLAN, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-08-10') AS START_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-08-09') AS END_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-08-10') AS UPDATED_AT
  UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS ID, 15000 AS REVENUE, FALSE AS TERMINATED_PLAN, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-08-10') AS START_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-08-09') AS END_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-08-10') AS UPDATED_AT
  UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS ID, 10000 AS REVENUE, FALSE AS TERMINATED_PLAN, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-08-10') AS START_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-08-09') AS END_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-08-10') AS UPDATED_AT
  UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS ID, 0 AS REVENUE, TRUE AS TERMINATED_PLAN, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-08-10') AS START_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-09-09') AS END_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-08-10') AS UPDATED_AT
  UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS ID, 5000 AS REVENUE, FALSE AS TERMINATED_PLAN, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-10-10') AS START_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-10-09') AS END_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-08-10') AS UPDATED_AT
  UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS ID, 10000 AS REVENUE, FALSE AS TERMINATED_PLAN, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-10-11') AS START_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-10-10') AS END_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-08-10') AS UPDATED_AT
)
select 
ID,
revenue, 
start_date,
end_date,
TERMINATED_PLAN
,revenue - lag(revenue, 1, NULL) over (partition by id order by updated_at asc) as diff_mrr
,CASE WHEN diff_mrr IS NULL THEN 'New Business'
    WHEN TERMINATED_PLAN = TRUE and diff_mrr < 0 then 'Churn'
    WHEN diff_mrr <0 then 'Contraction' 
    WHEN diff_mrr >0 AND lag(TERMINATED_PLAN, 1, NULL) over (partition by id order by updated_at asc) = FALSE then 'Expansion'
    WHEN diff_mrr >0 AND lag(TERMINATED_PLAN, 1, NULL) over (partition by id order by updated_at asc) = TRUE then 'Reactivation'    
END AS Transaction
from CTE
GROUP BY
  ID,
  revenue, 
  start_date,
  end_date,
  TERMINATED_PLAN,
  updated_at
order by updated_at asc;
```